# Error using components from Vuetify in vuejs webpack project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

I have a project in Vue and I want to use some Vuetify components. I have added Vuetify using `vue add vuetify` and everything looks fine. I also configured the loader in webpack.config.js but when I try to import components from the vuetify library I get this errors:

[image]

And nothing is being rendered.

This is the code of my component DataTable.vue where I want to import the vuetify components.

```
<template>
<div>
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import VDataTable from 'vuetify/lib';
import VApp from 'vuetify/lib'

export default {
    props:{
        url: {type: String,default: null},
    },
    components: {
      VDataTable,
      VApp
    },
    data () {
        return {
            tabId: `table${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000)}`,
            table: null,
            headers: [
              {
                text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
                align: 'left',
                sortable: false,
                value: 'name'
              },
              { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
              { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
              { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
              { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
              { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }
            ],
            desserts: [
              {
                name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
                calories: 159,
                fat: 6.0,
                carbs: 24,
                protein: 4.0,
                iron: '1%'
              },
              {
                name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
                calories: 237,
                fat: 9.0,
                carbs: 37,
                protein: 4.3,
                iron: '1%'
              },
              {
                name: 'Eclair',
                calories: 262,
                fat: 16.0,
                carbs: 23,
                protein: 6.0,
                iron: '7%'
              },
              {
                name: 'Cupcake',
                calories: 305,
                fat: 3.7,
                carbs: 67,
                protein: 4.3,
                iron: '8%'
              },
              {
                name: 'Gingerbread',
                calories: 356,
                fat: 16.0,
                carbs: 49,
                protein: 3.9,
                iron: '16%'
              },
              {
                name: 'Jelly bean',
                calories: 375,
                fat: 0.0,
                carbs: 94,
                protein: 0.0,
                iron: '0%'
              },
              {
                name: 'Lollipop',
                calories: 392,
                fat: 0.2,
                carbs: 98,
                protein: 0,
                iron: '2%'
              },
              {
                name: 'Honeycomb',
                calories: 408,
                fat: 3.2,
                carbs: 87,
                protein: 6.5,
                iron: '45%'
              },
              {
                name: 'Donut',
                calories: 452,
                fat: 25.0,
                carbs: 51,
                protein: 4.9,
                iron: '22%'
              },
              {
                name: 'KitKat',
                calories: 518,
                fat: 26.0,
                carbs: 65,
                protein: 7,
                iron: '6%'
              }
            ]
        }
    },
    mounted() {
    },
    created(){
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the main.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import router from './router';
import App from './components/App.vue';
import './components/bootstrap/globals.js';
import ToggleButton from 'vue-js-toggle-button'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify' // path to vuetify export

Vue.use(ToggleButton)

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  router,
  vuetify,
  components: { App }
}).$mount(`#app`);
```

This is the plugin/vuetify.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

And this is my webpack.config.js file where I set up the loaders:

```
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require(`vue-loader`);
const nodeSassMagicImporter = require(`node-sass-magic-importer`);
const path = require(`path`);

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require(`html-webpack-plugin`);
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require(`mini-css-extract-plugin`);
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require(`optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin`);
const UglifyJsPlugin = require(`uglifyjs-webpack-plugin`);
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin')

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const minify = env === `production`;
const sourceMap = env === `development`;

const config = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, `src`, `main.js`),
  mode: env,
  output: {
    publicPath: `/`,
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      // Must be specified for HtmlWebpackPlugin to work correctly.
      // See: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/882
      chunks: `all`,
    },
  },
  devtool: sourceMap ? `cheap-module-eval-source-map` : undefined,
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: `vue-loader`,
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,  
        include: /node_modules/,  
        loaders: ['css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: `babel-loader`,
        include: [path.join(__dirname, `src`)],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
        use: [
          `vue-style-loader`,
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass'),
              fiber: require('fibers')
            }
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new VuetifyLoaderPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: path.join(__dirname, `dist`, `index.html`),
      template: path.join(__dirname, `static`, `index.html`),
      inject: true,
      minify: minify ? {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true,
        // More options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      } : false,
    }),
  ]
};

if (minify) {
  config.optimization.minimizer = [
    new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin(),
    // Enabled by default in production mode if
    // the `minimizer` option isn't overridden.
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      cache: true,
      parallel: true,
    }),
  ];
}

if (env !== `development`) {
  config.plugins.push(new MiniCssExtractPlugin());

  const sassLoader = config.module.rules.find(({ test }) => test.test(`.scss`));
  // Replace the `vue-style-loader` with
  // the MiniCssExtractPlugin loader.
  sassLoader.use[0] = MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader;
}

module.exports = config;
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've been changing the configuration multiple times but I don't know why it's not working, the loaders is okay because before I was getting an error with that. Where I have to put new? If I write `vuetify: new vuetify` in main.js I get another error so I don't know how to fix that. Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide a sandbox with all the project files

Comment: Are you sure it's not meant to be `import { VApp, VDataTable } from 'vuetify/lib'`? Looks like you should be following [these instructions](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte/#a-la-carte-treeshaking)